# How can I get the value of Usage in Service Quotas on AWS through aws ali?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I have created two instances with the package information t2.micro.
When I checked with service-quotes, there were 02 instances. How can I use AWS CLI (or API) to get value at Usage?

Hope you can help me.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the total value of instances in region using something like this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId" --output text | wc -w
```

Answer (score 0):

[Refer this, Maybe you can get some insights](https://www.cloudconformity.com/knowledge-base/aws/TrustedAdvisor/service-limits.html)